# Constructing a semidirect product in GAP using characters

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, gap, programming, irreducible-representation

I have a finite group $G$ and an elementary abelian group $E(p^h)$ where $p\not \mid |G|$. I just want to construct via GAP the semidirect product $E(p^h):G$ given by a character $\chi$ of $G$, not necessarly irreducible. How can I do that?
In the case of an Irreducible character I have found the `IrreducibleRepresentationsDixon` to be the perfect first step to construct it but I cannot proceed further, any ideas?

Comment: A reducible representation is just a direct sum (i.e. block diagonal matrices) of its irreducible constituents. Build the irreducible representations and combine.

Comment: My problem is even with irreducible representation, since I have matrices how I can obtain an automorphism of the group itself in GAP. Mathematically it's clear how it works but in GAP coul be hard to translate it

Comment: Why would this be hard to translate? Have you looked at the manual examples? Maybe describe your example concretely as far as you can go and describe where you're stuck.